# libjpeg reads a scanline 1/8th the original width

Tags: c, libjpeg

I am trying to just read every pixel in a jpeg image. When I read a scanline, it appears that the image has been squashed to one eighth the size of the original image. The scanline is the correct width but the remaining 7/8'ths of the scanline are not filled (0, 0, 0).

I cant simply use each pixel 8 times since a large amount of information was lost.

I don't use any decompression parameters and am perfectly happy with the defaults. The Libjpeg version I am using is "libjpeg/9d" from the https://conan.io package center.

How can I get scanlines in the correct aspect ratio?

```
FILE* file_p = openfile(fileaddress);
struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
struct jpeg_error_mgr err; //the error handler
cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error( &err ); 
jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, file_p);
int result = jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);
bool startedfine = jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);
int row_stride = cinfo.output_width * cinfo.output_components;
image output = create_image(cinfo.output_width, cinfo.output_height);
JSAMPARRAY buffer = calloc(1, sizeof(JSAMPROW*));
buffer[0] = calloc(1, sizeof(JSAMPROW) * row_stride);

while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height) {
    int current_y = cinfo.output_scanline;
    jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, buffer, 1);
    JSAMPROW row = buffer[0];

    for(int row_i = 0; row_i < row_stride; row_i += 3) {
        int r = (int)row[row_i];
        int g = (int)row[row_i + 1];
        int b = (int)row[row_i + 2];
        int actual_x = row_i / 3;
        output.pixels_array_2d[actual_x][current_y].r = r;
        output.pixels_array_2d[actual_x][current_y].g = b;
        output.pixels_array_2d[actual_x][current_y].b = g;
    }
}
free(buffer[0]);
free(buffer);
jpeg_finish_decompress(&cinfo);  
jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);
fclose(file_p);
```

As a side note, you may notice I assign the blue value to the green value when copying the pixels. This is because without it, my test image is the wrong colour and I don't know why.

Comment: Is there any unusual metadata in the image? Have you tried on some reference images?

Comment: I havent tried that yet and will report my further experiments to you.

Comment: Who made the image you are decompressing? The scan lines are not filled *and* the green/blue are transposed? What does a regular image viewer to with it?

Comment: @tadman I ran another test using this image and it still comes out squished. https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/isolated-black-white-simple-minimalist-260nw-1895967982.jpg

Comment: @WeatherVane I made the image in paint. Yes, both of your other questions are true. A regular image viewer such as Windows Photos opens it normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I needed to call the `tjDecompress2` function and give the correct pitch value as argument.

```
tjDecompress2(
    handle,
    jpegBuffer,
    jpegSize,
    scaledBuffer,
    scaledWidth,
    0,
    scaledHeight,
    pixelFormat,
    flags);
```

Here is a [link to the libraries documentation](https://%20https://rawcdn.githack.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/main/doc/html/group___turbo_j_p_e_g.html#gae9eccef8b682a48f43a9117c231ed013) on this parameter.